# R code for new CKD equation - with "if" statements

Tags: r

I'm new to coding in R and am having a difficult time coding the following equation

[CKD EPI Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoLFU.png)

142 x (Scr/A)^B x 0.9938^age x (1.012 if female)

Female

- Scr <=0.7; A = 0.7, B = -0.241
- Scr >0.7; A = 0.7, B = -1.2

Male

- Scr <=0.9; A = 0.9, B = -0.302
- Scr >0.9; A = 0.9, B = -1.2

(There is an existing R package for the old version of this equation, but not this updated one).

Could someone help me with the code? Having a hard time figuring out how to create a new variable (eGFR) with values calculated from this equation. The components A and B of the equation depend on 2 categories of variable Scr (serum creatinine) and on gender (M/F). Thanks!

```
    wave1.data$baseline.egfr <- (if(wave1.data$Sex=="Male") {M1 <- wave1.data$Creatinine >= 0.9
      M2 <- wave1.data$Creatinine < 0.9
      eGFR <- (142*(wave1.data$Creatinine/A1)^-0.302*(0.9938^wave1.data$Age))
      eGFR <- (142*(wave1.data$Creatinine/A2)^-1.2*(0.9938^wave1.data$Age))}
    else if(wave1.data$Sex=="Female")
    {F1 <- wave1.data$Creatinine >= 0.7
    F2 <- wave1.data$Creatinine < 0.7
    eGFR <- (142*(wave1.data$Creatinine/A1)^-0.241*(0.9938^wave1.data$Age))
      eGFR <- (142*(wave1.data$Creatinine/A2)^-1.2*(0.9938^wave1.data$Age))})
```

Comment: Thank you! Just undeleted it - still new to SO, so deleted once I saw it was getting flagged. It's back up now! I am getting an error message after using the code you posted; do you know how to go about that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```r
eGFR <- function(Scr, age, sex) {
  sex <- tolower(sex)
  A <- ifelse(sex == "female", 0.7, 0.9)
  B <- ifelse(Scr > A, -1.2,
              ifelse(sex == "female", -0.241, -0.302))
  mult <- ifelse(sex == "female", 1.012, 1)
  
 round(142 * (Scr/A)^B * 0.9938^age * mult)
}

eGFR(0.6, 35, "male")
#> [1] 129

eGFR(0.75, 35, "Male")
#> [1] 121

eGFR(0.8, 80, "female")
#> [1] 74

eGFR(Scr = c(0.6, 0.8), age = c(35, 80), sex = c("male", "female"))
#> [1] 129  74
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi! I got this error message: 
Warning in if (sex == "female") 0.7 else 0.9 :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Warning in if (Scr > 0.7) -1.2 else if (sex == "female") mult <- if (sex ==  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Error in if (Scr > 0.7) -1.2 else if (sex == "female") mult <- if (sex ==  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: this won't work with vectors as input.

Comment: you can "fix it" by `eGFR <- Vectorize(eGFR)`. But there is a way to write this so it takes vectors upfront. Let me think about it..

Comment: also, remember you need to write `"Male"` and `"Female"` in the function, exactly as it appears in your data.

Comment: @AndreaL I didn't realise you needed vectorized input. See my update.

Comment: Thank you! Added/fixed both. Now when I type code: baseline.set$eGFR_baseline <- eGFR(Scr = baseline.set$Creatinine, age = baseline.set$Age, sex = baseline.set$Sex) I get error message: Error in if (Scr > 0.7) -1.2 else if (sex == "Female") mult <- if (sex == : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: I have also fixed it to ignore case, so it should work equally well with "Male", "male", "MALE" etc

Comment: @AndreaL you shouldn't be getting that error with the new function, if you copy and paste the above update into your R console this should work

Comment: @AllanCameron No more error message, thank you! I tried to cross reference by inputting the values into this validated calculator (https://www.mdcalc.com/ckd-epi-equations-glomerular-filtration-rate-gfr#evidence) and am getting different values. Was there anything missed in the code, such as if Male Scr <= 0.9 vs >0.9? I'm not sure

Comment: @AndreaL see my update. This now gives identical results to mdcalc, but takes vectorized input, so should work directly on data frame columns. If this has answered your question, please consider marking it as sccepted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope this function well represents the formula for individual case:

```
ckdi <- function(sex_i, scr, age){
  female_scr <- c(0, 0.7)
  male_scr <- c(0, 0.9)
  female_A <- c(0.7, 0.7)
  female_B <- c(-0.241, -1.2)
  male_A <- c(0.9, 0.9)
  male_B <- c(-0.302, -1.2)
  
  if(sex_i == "F"){
    scrid <- findInterval(scr, female_scr, left.open = TRUE)
    A <- female_A[scrid]
    B <- female_B[scrid]
    k <- 1.012
  }
  if(sex_i == "M"){
    scrid <- findInterval(scr, male_scr, left.open = TRUE)
    A <- male_A[scrid]
    B <- male_B[scrid]
    k<- 1.000
  }
  result_i <- 142*(scr/A)^B * 0.9938^age * k
  return(result_i)
}
```

To apply to multiple data, `mapply` can be used. For example:

```
set.seed(1)
scr_all <- runif(3)
age_all <- runif(3, 30,50)
sex_all <- c("F", "M", "F")

mapply(ckdi, sex_all, scr_all, age_all)
#       F        M        F 
#134.5373 150.0365 111.9148
```